# Could not download kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.0): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

My project was running fine few days back. When I opened the project now it keep giving me an error on running the build

"Could not download kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.0): No cached version available for offline mode
"

My gradle offline option is disabled and I am connected to active internet as well.

I have not made any changes to my project except updating Android studio to version  3.3.2

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to go to **File> Settings> Gradle** and disable the option "**Offline work**"

The error message is indicating that kotlin cannot download the file (*kotlin-reflect.jar*) from the indicated address (*org.jetbrains.kotlin: kotlin-reflect: 1.3.0*) and that Gradle does not have a local version (*offline mode*) of it; you must allow Gradle to download the file and that option is preventing it.

good wishes and good code!

Answer (score 1):

Just clean/ rebuild your project.

If this doesn't work, try to invalidate and restart your IDE.

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: I tried cleaning the project , I even deleted the build folder but its not working. Strange. I have been into this problem previously and cleaning the project use to work fine for me

Comment: Please, try one last thing, sync your project with gradle files. Go to Files -> Sync project with gradle files.

Comment: Nopes no help with that as well  :(

Comment: Hey it worked with the option below Synch Project which is Re-import gradle project thanks a lot for pointing it out in the right direction

Comment: Thats great! Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

try the version 1.3.50,it's working.

https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar

Answer (score 0):

File-Invalidate Caches，it's working for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31982127)